# Stacks and their implementation

Tags: c++, stack

I am confused in how stacks work, if you have a stack like

```
stack<string,vector<int>>
```

I understand the container is a container of the type of vector, which contains intergers, but then what is the purpose of the string? Or even if its not string, maybe its a bool. What purpose does the first argument serve?

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <stack>         
#include <vector>         
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   stack<string,vector<int> > third;  
    third.emplace(1);


  cout << "size of third: " << third.size() << '\n';

}
```

Comment: You know you could try to write a small program that tries to use that stack and see what error the compiler throws at you.

Comment: Documentation also always helps in this sort of situation:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/?kw=stack

Comment: [Or perhaps here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

Answer (score 3):

Your...

```
stack<string,vector<int>>
```

...is not the right way to use the `std::stack` template.  Almost always you simply need one template parameter, which is the value type for elements in the stack, so `stack<string>` would be relatively common, and `stack<vector<int>>` is entirely plausible but less often seen.

The second parameter is there so you can specify an alternative container over which the `stack` API should be layered, and not something you normally need to vary as the default of `std::deque<T>`, where `T` is the first template parameter to `stack`, is generally just fine.

If you did need to specify a second template parameter, it would usually be `some_container<T>`, rather than the legal-but-misleading mismatch of `string` for `T` and `vector<int>` postulated in your question.  Confusingly, the actual type of the first template parameter to `stack` is only used to specify the default of `std::deque<T>` for the second parameter - the container type.  The stack's actual element type is taken from the container type, so when you explicitly specify a container type then the first template parameter to `stack<>` is just a place-holder and is functionally ignored.  This is unfortunate - I'd argue that the Standard requiring a static assertion that the first parameter matches the container's element_type would be useful protection against misleading code.

There are limitations on the container type too - it needs to support certain functions and provide certain types/typedefs for `stack` to use it for the actual data storage.

Answer (score 2):

`stack<string,vector<int>>` makes no sense, it's a stack of strings which is stored in a vector of ints. Obviously that doesn't work.

`stack<int>` is a stack of ints which is stored in a `deque<int>` (the default).

`stack<int,vector<int>>` is a stack of ints which is stored in a vector of ints.

`stack<int,MyCustomStorage>` is a stack of ints which is stored in a custom class (which obviously you have to write yourself).

**Edit**

It appears that in the template `stack<T,C>` `T` is only used to provide a default for `C`, it defaults to `deque<T>`. The type of the elements in the stack is always `C::value_type`.

Comment: @user2521432: why don't you post a complete minimal program that shows it working?

Comment: @user2521432 That's interesting. I tried it, and it also works. What's happening in my implementation is that the std::string is unused. So the fact that it doesn't match std::vector<int> doesn't matter. That fact that it works doesn't make it right though.

Comment: oh well I forgot to include the std namespace, but it works nonetheless

Comment: It works technically in that example.  I couldn't imagine why you would want to actually use the container like that, or in what fun and exciting ways various implementations will break under those conditions.

Comment: I mean I not saying I want to use it, but the implementation confused me in how stacks work.

Comment: @user2521432 Surprised me to, I was expecting a compiler error.

Comment: Will `stack<vector<int>>` work same as `stack<int,vector<int>>`?

Comment: @Nikhil No, `stack<vector<int>>` is a stack of vectors, `stack<int,vector<int>>` is a stack of ints.

Comment: @Nikhil: no... `stack<vector<int>>` would work the same as `stack<X,deque<vector<int>>>` where `X` is any type and of no relevance.